# Memory/Performance of Using SQL Server CE

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, memory-management, sql-server-ce

So I am working in an embedded environment and there is a need to transfer all of the data from a SQL Server Compact Edition database (.sdf file) to a SQLite database. So this would be a one time operation and my concern is that if I connect to the CE database to retrieve the data, will this cause additional memory and CPU resources to be used and stick around after I am done reading the data? My hope is that all the resources used by SQL Server CE would be garbage collected and freed up after I am done reading from the CE database or else I may be forced to write my own .sdf parser/reader.

Does anyone know ow the resources for SQL Server CE will be handled after I am done connecting to the database and if I can safely assume that they will be freed up after I read the data?

Comment: Why does that concern you?  Have you actually performed tests and found that your concerns are valid?  It seems doubtful that anything you could write on your own would be any better.  I would suggest writing a simple program as a test and seeing if your concerns are valid.

Comment: It would make sense for this to concern you, if the transfer was going to happen every hour or even every day. But you say that this is a one-time operation! Even if it turns out that the transfer LEAKS memory that you never recover (which would surprise me) - go ahead and do the transfer, then reboot your embedded environment! Why is that a problem?

Comment: you're not being specific on how you are "transfering".  Are you connecting to the database, then selecting data table by table and insert into the SQLIte database?  Please edit your question on your proposed algorithm and then folks can help what to look out for.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you would have no concerns here.  The ce and express versions of sql server have imposed utilization limits.  I gb mem and 1 physical cpu and if you you are doing a one time batch process the mem will be GC after the process is stopped.